# Reading vim plugin - strange notation and navigation

Tags: vim

Im reading great tpope rails.vim and what does it mean:

```
" }}}1
" Abbreviations {{{1
```

exactly here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/autoload/rails.vim#L3921

Is it for better navigation?
This file is quite huge, how to navigate on it properly - using ctags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are so called foldmarkers. Vim 6 introduced code folding and the triple braces are the default string to mark the beginning and the end of a fold. In addition, if you prepend the opening mark `{{{` with text, it'll show in the collapsed line as a header. This is only one way to fold code. Being a manual method, it is easily controlled and thus preferred by many.

See `:h folding` and `:h fold-marker`.

Comment: Your answer is not true in this part: *This is the only way to fold code.*. See `:h 'foldmethod'`.

Comment: @ZyX: agreed if I ever wrote such a thing :)

Comment: @ZyX, you didn't read progo's comment carefully: he wrote _This is only one way…_ (implying that other methods exist) not _This is the only way…_.